# vb.net multi thread chat client and server

Tags: vb.net

i have created a chat server for chatting. there i connect the client pc's that will allow to chat them. In my case, server allow me to connect with that, but i can't able to chat with others make use of my application. Please see my code and correct it. here is my code.

**Client side code:**

```
 Imports System.Net.Sockets
    Imports System.Text
    Public Class Form1
        Dim clientSocket As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
        Dim serverStream As NetworkStream
        Dim readData As String
        Dim infiniteCounter As Integer

        Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim outStream As Byte() = _
            System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TextBox2.Text + "$")
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length)
            serverStream.Flush()
        End Sub

        Private Sub msg()
            If Me.InvokeRequired Then
                Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf msg))
            Else
                TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + " >> " + readData
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
            readData = "Conected to Chat Server ..."
            msg()
            clientSocket.Connect("192.168.1.215", 8888)
            'Label1.Text = "Client Socket Program - Server Connected ..."
            serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream()

            Dim outStream As Byte() = _
            System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TextBox3.Text + "$")
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length)
            serverStream.Flush()

            Dim ctThread As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf getMessage)
            ctThread.Start()
        End Sub

        Private Sub getMessage()
            For infiniteCounter = 1 To 2
                infiniteCounter = 1
                serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
                Dim buffSize As Integer
                Dim inStream(10024) As Byte
                buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize
                serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize)
                Dim returndata As String = _
                System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream)
                readData = "" + returndata
                msg()
            Next
        End Sub
    End Class
```

**server side Code:**

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text
Module Module1
    Dim clientsList As New Hashtable
    Sub Main()
        Dim serverSocket As New TcpListener(8888)
        Dim clientSocket As TcpClient
        Dim infiniteCounter As Integer
        Dim counter As Integer

        serverSocket.Start()
        msg("Chat Server Started ....")
        counter = 0
        infiniteCounter = 0
        For infiniteCounter = 1 To 2
            infiniteCounter = 1
            counter += 1
            clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient()

            Dim bytesFrom(10024) As Byte
            Dim dataFromClient As String

            Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = _
            clientSocket.GetStream()
            networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, CInt(clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))
            dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom)
            dataFromClient = _
            dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"))

            clientsList(dataFromClient) = clientSocket

            broadcast(dataFromClient + " Joined ", dataFromClient, False)

            msg(dataFromClient + " Joined chat room ")
            Dim client As New handleClinet
            client.startClient(clientSocket, dataFromClient, clientsList)
        Next

        clientSocket.Close()
        serverSocket.Stop()
        msg("exit")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Sub msg(ByVal mesg As String)
        mesg.Trim()
        Console.WriteLine(" >> " + mesg)
    End Sub
    Private Sub broadcast(ByVal msg As String, _
    ByVal uName As String, ByVal flag As Boolean)
        Dim Item As DictionaryEntry
        For Each Item In clientsList
            Dim broadcastSocket As TcpClient
            broadcastSocket = CType(Item.Value, TcpClient)
            Dim broadcastStream As NetworkStream = _
                    broadcastSocket.GetStream()
            Dim broadcastBytes As [Byte]()

            If flag = True Then
                broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(uName + " says : " + msg)
            Else
                broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg)
            End If

            broadcastStream.Write(broadcastBytes, 0, broadcastBytes.Length)
            broadcastStream.Flush()
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Class handleClinet
        Dim clientSocket As TcpClient
        Dim clNo As String
        Dim clientsList As Hashtable

        Public Sub startClient(ByVal inClientSocket As TcpClient, _
        ByVal clineNo As String, ByVal cList As Hashtable)
            Me.clientSocket = inClientSocket
            Me.clNo = clineNo
            Me.clientsList = cList
            Dim ctThread As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf doChat)
            ctThread.Start()
        End Sub

        Private Sub doChat()
            Dim infiniteCounter As Integer
            Dim requestCount As Integer
            Dim bytesFrom(10024) As Byte
            Dim dataFromClient As String
            Dim sendBytes As [Byte]()
            Dim serverResponse As String
            Dim rCount As String
            requestCount = 0
            For infiniteCounter = 1 To 2
                infiniteCounter = 1
                Try
                    requestCount = requestCount + 1
                    Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = _
                            clientSocket.GetStream()
                    networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, CInt(clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))
                    dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom)
                    dataFromClient = _
                        dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"))
                    msg("From client - " + clNo + " : " + dataFromClient)
                    rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount)

                    broadcast(dataFromClient, clNo, True)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
                End Try
            Next
        End Sub

    End Class
End Module
```

Comment: You need to ask specific questions, not "fix my code for me". If you don't put forth the effort to come up with a question it is unlikely anyone here will be motivated to help you.

Answer (score 1):

One, you need to specify your PUBLIC IP address, second, you need to open port 8888 on your router.

Change: clientSocket.Connect("192.168.1.215", 8888) to:

clientSocket.Connect("", 8888)

And make sure to forward port 8888 to your internal LAN IP: 192.168.1.215

Also this is entirely unsecure, I would encrypt and decrypt the strings using triple DES. A little bit of security but at least its security.

Learn a bit about networking bud.